# How to associate these models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm tried a lot of ways to associate these models in a good and clean way, but as usual of any beginner I'm doing something stupid that I can't see. Please, can someone would help me out?

**user model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :house,  :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :house, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**house model**

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs-to :type
end
```

**type model**

```
class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :houses
accepts_nested_attributes_for :houses
end
```

**type controller**

```
class TypesController < ApplicationController
  def new 
    @type = Type.new 
  end

  def create
    @type = Type.new(params[:type]) 
    @type.houses = current_user.house

    if @type.save
      redirect_to edit_house_path
      flash[:success] = "yeah"
    else
      render :new
      end
    end
 end
```

**type new_view**

```
<div>
<%= form_for @type, :url =>  types_path, :method => :post  do |t| %>

 <%= t.fields_for :house do |h| %>
<%= h.label :name %><%= h.text_field :name %>
<% end %>

<ul>
<li>test_1:<%= t.radio_button :kind, "test_1" %></li>
<li>test_2:<%= t.radio_button :kind, "test_2" %></li>
<li>test_3:<%= t.radio_button :kind, "test_3" %></li>
</ul>
<%= t.submit "create", :class => "blue" %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your real problem. Be more specific please

Comment: the problem is: the user i'll create the the house and type at the same time, so every time that i try assign both rails spit out this problem: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: house and then when i put just house on type attr_assible show up this new error : unknown attribute: house

Comment: the problem is, the house is not assigned to user yet, this is what i'm trying to do on type create controller!

Answer (score 2):

You need use the named of association in field_for so it's

```
<%= t.fields_for :houses do |h| %>
```

instead of

```
<%= t.fields_for :house do |h| %>
```

Comment: i tried this, but i don't know why now the text_field of the house disappear

Comment: i think that because i'm not using the build method.

Comment: Yes, if there are no houses define, you can't see it. You need allways  build your associate object before see it on your form_field. It's like the object associate to your form_for. You need build it.

Comment: done, now how i associate the current_user with house and type?

Comment: i think that associate the current_user third model on this that's the tricky!

Comment: so far you're right, thank you very much, the name have to be pluralized on many association!

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is that the nested house in your type object doesn't exist when creating the type, you'll need to add something like the following to your new action before displaying the new_type form:

```
@type.houses.build(:user_id => current_user.id)
```

Which will allow your fields_for form elements to work, and the @type.save function to correctly create the nested resource in the create action.

Comment: many thank's jon, i already did this, but now can't associate the current_user to house and type

Comment: because the current_user just request the one house on this creation.

Comment: thanks for the help jon, but still assign just the type and the house, the user still out of this assignment, i'll try to do this on the house controller!